# Filtering rows on multiple string conditions at the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter a dataframe on multiple conditions. Let's say I have one column called 'detail', i want to get a dataframe where the 'detail' column values match the following:

```
detail = unidecode.unidecode(str(row['detail']).lower())
```

So now I have all `detail` rows unidecoded and to lowercase, then i want to extract the rows that start with some substring like:

```py
detail.startswith('bomb')
```

And finally also take the rows where another integer column equals 100.

I tried to do this but obviously it doesn't work:

```
llista_dfs['df_bombes'] = df_filtratge[df_filtratge['detail'].str.lower().startswith('bomb') or df_filtratge['family']==100]
```

This line above is what I would like to execute but I'm not sure which is the syntax to be able to achieve this in a single line of code (if that's possible).

That's an example of what the code should do:

**Initial table:**

```
    detail            family
0   bòmba             90
1   boMbá             87
2   someword          100
3   someotherword     65
4   Bombá             90
```

**Result table:**

```
    detail             family
0   bòmba              90
1   boMbá              87
2   someword           100
4   Bombá              90
```

Comment: Use bitwise or: `|` with your conditions and your code looks fine

Comment: You could avoid the usage of `unidecode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually @user3483203's comment is the right solution as to filter in pandas you use `&` and `|` instead of `and` and `or`. In any case in case you want to get rid of `unidecode` you might use this solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

txt="""0   bòmba             90
1   boMbá             87
2   someword          100
3   someotherword     65
4   Bombá             90"""

df = [list(filter(lambda x: x!='', t.split(' ')))[1:] 
      for t in txt.split("\n")]

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=["details", 'family'])
df["family"] = df["family"].astype(int)

cond1 = df["details"].str.normalize('NFKD')\
                     .str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')\
                     .str.decode('utf-8')\
                     .str.lower()\
                     .str.startswith('bomba')

cond2 = df["family"]==100

df[cond1 | cond2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, may I ask why backslashes (\\) are used at the end of every str call?

Comment: It's just to say that there are still methods to apply on the next line. You could potentially use when there is a new dot. I used it to satisfy the 79 chars per line convention. Plus, imo, it's easier to read/understand.